# Trying to add a child block to adminhtml form

Tags: php, forms, magento, parent-child

I am stuck a little with following problem:
I created a Fom in the adminhtml area using the pure php from Magento and standard template.
This all works as expected, but I cannot dynamically add and remove fields, I need Javascript and my own phtml file for that.

My Idea now was to simply include a childblock which is using a custom template at the end of the form.

So far I have added

```
$cblock =$this->getLayout()
->createBlock('netcon_konmod/adminhtml_caps_edit_mat')
->setTemplate('netcon_konmod_mat.phtml');

$this->_addContent($this->getLayout()
->createBlock('netcon_konmod/adminhtml_caps_edit')->setChild($cblock));
```

to my controller, created an empty Netcon_Konmod_Block_Adminhtml_Caps_Edit_Mat class which extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget

and created template file mat.phtml in .../template/netcon/konmod/

I also have my konmod.xml which updates my layout and which includes

```
<adminhtml_caps_edit>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="netcon_konmod/adminhtml_caps_edit" name="netcon_konmod_caps_edit">
            <block type="netcon_konmod/adminhtml_caps_edit_mat" name="netcon_konmod_caps_mat" template="netcon_konmod_mat.phtml" />
        </block>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_caps_edit>
```

I am rather new to Magento, and until now I only found ways to include a child block by calling getChildHtml from an already existing phtml file of the parent block.
However, since I create my form completely with the form and fieldset methods, I don't have my own phtml file in which I could include that call.

The way I have it set up right now, it is displaying the form normally, but does not include the childblock.

Any help would be appreciated, if it is at all possible to do this, I would like to avoid recoding my whole form as template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$childBlock = $this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('konmod/adminhtml_caps_edit_mat')
            ->setTemplate('netcon_konmod_mat.phtml');

$this->_addContent($this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('konmod/adminhtml_caps_edit')
          //->setTemplate('netcon_konmod_mat.phtml')
          ->append($childBlock));
```

Comment: Also another thing I noticed is, that while everywhere else Magento translates underscores to slashes itself to figure out pathnames, when I set a Template, I have to use slashes instead of underscores. So I needed to change netcon_konmod_mat.phtml to netcon/konmod/mat.phtml.